# Underfull\hbox (badness10000) in paragraph at lines 31--43

Tags: errors, listings, lists, texmaker, paragraphs

```
a.) Probetas de acr\'ilico transparente, con escala de alturas graduada y con tap\'on de hule.\\
b.) Tubo irrigador de acero inoxidable, provisto de un tramo de manguera de hule y con un sif\'on.\\ 
c.) Pis\'on met\'alico con peso de $1000gr \pm 5gr$.\\
d.) C\'apsulas met\'alicas de 57 mm de di\'ametro, con capacidad $85ge \pm 5cm^{3}$\\
e.) Embudo de vidrio o pl\'astico, de boca ancha, de 10 cm de di\'ametro.\\ 
f.) Cron\'ometro o reloj, con lectura en minutos y segundos.\\ 
g.) Dos botellas de vidrio o de pl\'astico con capacidad m\'inima de 3.78 litros\\ 
h.) Balanza de 2 kg. de capacidad y $0.1gr$ de aproximaci\'on.\\ 
i.) Horno con termostato que mantenga una temperatura de $105gr \pm 5^{\circ}C$.\\ 
j.) Papel filtro con velocidad de filtrado r\'apida.\\
k.) Soluci\'on de reserva\\
l.) Soluci\'on de trabajo\\
```

I don´t know what is wrong with me.

Comment: What are you using? This isn't LaTeX nor TeX...

Comment: Please see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner

Answer (score 1):

The wrong thing is that just posted a text file --- LaTeX (or TeX) is a different thing, a bit like a programming language. You should really read *A not-so-short introduction to LaTeX*, [available in Spanish too](https://tobi.oetiker.ch/lshort/lshort.pdf).

Your example, in (very) minimal LaTeX, would be:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[spanish]{babel}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}[label={\alph*.)}]
    \item Probetas de acr\'ilico transparente, con escala de alturas graduada y con tap\'on de hule.
    \item Tubo irrigador de acero inoxidable, provisto de un tramo de manguera de hule y con un sif\'on. 
    \item Pis\'on met\'alico con peso de $1000gr \pm 5gr$.
    \item C\'apsulas met\'alicas de 57 mm de di\'ametro, con capacidad $85ge \pm 5cm^{3}$ 
    \item Embudo de vidrio o pl\'astico, de boca ancha, de 10 cm de di\'ametro. 
    \item Cron\'ometro o reloj, con lectura en minutos y segundos. 
    \item Dos botellas de vidrio o de pl\'astico con capacidad m\'inima de 3.78 litros 
    \item Balanza de 2 kg. de capacidad y $0.1gr$ de aproximaci\'on. 
    \item Horno con termostato que mantenga una temperatura de $105gr \pm 5^{\circ}C$. 
    \item Papel filtro con velocidad de filtrado r\'apida.
    \item Soluci\'on de reserva
    \item Soluci\'on de trabajo
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

But there is not really any need to use command for accented chars in 2016... and I am very partial to measurement units in italic...

[image]

Comment: Good, but maybe you can also add `siunitx` for proper typesetting of units; by the way, “gr” is not the official symbol for the gram.

Comment: @egreg, Yep, I know. I even fighted with an author in a scientific paper review about that. Will add this, but this question made me think about tutorials, and for that I added a question... http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297463/latex-introduction-2-the-come-back (morover, notice that the OP says "105gr ± 5ºC" (?????)