# Error in a LaTeX formula

Tags: math-mode, errors

```
$$\hat{\alpha} = \begin{cases}

\tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}, \, if  \hat{\alpha_1}>0 \, \hat{\alpha_2}>0 \\

\tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+\pi, \, if \hat{\alpha_1}<0\\

 \tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha_1}}{\hat{\alpha_2}}+2\pi, \, if \hat{\alpha_2}<0 \, \hat{\alpha_1} >0 \\

 undefined,  \hat{\alpha_2}=0 \, \hat{\alpha_1}=0 \\

 \end{cases}$$
```

This message appears

```
Paragraph ended before \cases was complete
<to be read again>
                   \par
```

What does it mean?
how i can write in latex programme

Comment: Hi @rita-ana, welcome to tex.sx. I have formatted a bit your question to make it understandable. The direct problem is that you can't put blank lines (which are paragraph delimiters in LaTeX) in formulas. 
The more general problem is that you need to read some intro document to LaTeX, see for example  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11/what-are-good-learning-resources-for-a-latex-beginner and https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/297463/latex-introduction-books-2-modern-documentation. Moreover, a "help tour" of this site will be useful for the future

Answer (score 5):

You can leave no blank line in a math display.

I take the occasion for suggesting some improvements:

1. never use `$$`, see [Why is `\[ … \]` preferable to `$$`?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/503)
2. with `dcases*` the input is easier
3. even if `\hat{\alpha_2}` could be logically justified, the hat would fall in an awkward position and `\hat{\alpha}_2` looks much better

Here's the code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,mathtools}

\begin{document}

\begin{equation*}
\hat{\alpha} =
\begin{dcases*}
\tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha}_1}{\hat{\alpha}_2},        & if $\hat{\alpha}_1>0$ and $\hat{\alpha}_2>0$} \\
\tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha}_1}{\hat{\alpha}_2} + \pi,  & if $\hat{\alpha}_1<0$}\\
\tan^{-1}\frac{\hat{\alpha}_1}{\hat{\alpha}_2} + 2\pi, & if $\hat{\alpha}_2<0$ and $\hat{\alpha}_1 >0$} \\    
\text{undefined},                                      & if $\hat{\alpha}_2=0$ and $\hat{\alpha}_1=0$
\end{dcases*}
\end{equation*}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: However, one _can_ leave a blank line in `cases` (of course we completely agree that one _shouldn't_), though I've never noticed until today (since I'm a good boy and never leave blank lines in formulas `:-)`). The code in the question, as bad as it is, compiles fine (well, horribly, but no errors).

Comment: iam new student in this programme @ca