# our my document in latex the problem pf appear {paragraph ended befor \align was complete. <to be read again> \par

Tags: math-mode, align

```
\documentclass[14pt,english]{article}
\usepackage[margin=0.8in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}





\begin{align}


&=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\lambda\rho\sin(x_i-X_i)-\dfrac{1}{c}\sum_{i=1}^{n}\dfrac{-\beta_i\eta_1\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)+\beta_i\eta_2\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}{1-\alpha_1\cos(y_i-\beta_i X_i)-\alpha_2\sin(y_i-\beta_i X_i)}
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

Comment: downvoted: You keep asking the same thing over and over again, and ignore the answers that you are given. You can not have a blank line in an `align` environemnt.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/415086/35864

Answer (score 3):

If your document really look like described, the error is here:

```
\begin{align}

&=
```

An empty line means new paragraph, which is forbidden inside math.

Moreover, without additional package, e.g. `extarticle` in place of `article`, your option `14pt` will be ignored and all document will be in `10pt`.